# Is it a good idea to redirect http://www.example.com to http://example.com or keep both?

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect, no-www

Is it a good idea to redirect `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` or keep both ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good idea to redirect example.com to www.example.com. Because you can't use a CNAME for example.com's DNS record, which greatly reduces your options for things like load balancing and resilience.